# Font problems when exporting to EPS/LateX

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, label

I created a simple plot that I want to include in my latex document:

[image]
The font in the axis (both x and y) does not look like the font I used in my latex document, which is Utopia (regular). I want the axis to have the font Utopia as well but I did not succeed. I used the following:

```
  set(gca, 'XTick',[]);
  set(gca, 'YTick',[]);
  ylabel('Surface elevation','Fontsize',12,'Fontname','Utopia');
  xlabel(' Time', 'Fontsize',12,'Fontname','Utopia'); 
  set(gca,'FontSize',12,'Fontname','Utopia')
  set(findall(gcf,'Utopia','text'),'FontSize',15)
print -depsc figure_name
```

I tried to include Utopia, and I export it as EPS. How can I change it to Utopia (or any other font type)?

Comment: You need to embed the font within the EPS. There are no ways to do this directly using MATLAB built-ins. It appears that `export_fig` can do this for PDF files at least. There is a discussion here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154595

Comment: Or `matlabfrag` from the file exchange and `pstools`/`psfrag` in LaTeX work well.

Comment: After years of trying to get the fonts right in Matlab and other programs that I use for plots, I finally admitted defeat. Now I export the figures with the default fonts, and then manually touch up the figure with a vector graphics program (Adobe illustrator works best, Inkscape is also OK). This turned out to be faster, leads to better looking figures, and gives me more flexibility in adding annotations. Also, you can programmatically simplify paths (describe same path with less points) in the vector drawing program, leading to smaller figures and faster/snappier PDF document.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution if you have some experience with Illustrator / Inkscape. An alternative would be to use [Matlab2Ti*k*Z](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) to convert the plot to a Ti*k*Z graphic, which you compile with LaTeX, i.e. the correct fonts, sizes, etc. The downside: longer compilation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked all possible ways to embed the font within the EPS and then include it in LateX. I find the solution with Matlab2Tikz the easiest. A brief summary how to do this:

1. You create your own plot in Matlab with your preferred fonts, fontsize, etc.
2. Download Matlab2TikZ: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz and include it in your path.
3. In Matlab do the following: matlab2tikz('filename.tikz', ...)
4. In Latex, include pgfplots package. (\usepackage(pgfplots)).
5. An example how to include in LateX can be found here: http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/

Matlab2TikZ is very straightforward and a beginner with Matlab/Latex can use it without too much troubles!